# how to convert array of unsigned char to unsigned short integer

Tags: c++

how to convert an array of `unsigned char` of 4 character to a `unsigned short int`. each character is received from UART and stored in buffer of `unsigned char`

Comment: _"`unsigned char` of 4 character"_ Shouldn't you convert to `integer` or two `short` variables?

Comment: IIRC, 4 bytes doesn't usually fit into 2 bytes. (I know. Sizes may differ, but it's *still* not guaranteed)

Comment: if I send 4 unsigned char FF FF = 65535 it fit in unsigned short int

Comment: @MakhloufGharbi FF FF is 2 chars

Comment: @Stas no, each UART character received is one F, this is the protocol

Comment: The standard says that short integers are not smaller than a char. So you should be able to cast without loss of precision.

Comment: @MakhloufGharbi: Traditionally, we write that as: 0F 0F 0F 0F. A word of warning that this is not 65535. 65535 is 00 00 FF FF, but you said "each character received is one F". You seem confused.

Comment: no in fact it's a customized protocol i should follow, no choice

Comment: No "customized protocol" can change the fundamental rules of mathematics or of how _counting_ works, @Makhlouf.

Comment: yes in fact it's `0F 0F 0F 0F` what i meant is that each number is in one char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you have four bytes of input, each holding a 4-bit nibble. In that case you can use something like this:

```
unsigned short int result;
unsigned char buffer[4];

...

result = buffer[0] << 12;
result |= buffer[1] << 8;
result |= buffer[2] << 4;
result |= buffer[3];
```

This code assumes that the high nibble of each character is zero. For a little endian input, reverse the indexes to be descending.

Comment: no I have 4 bytes of input, for FFFF for example, there is  4 unsigned char of  F, it's the protocol which is made like that

Comment: @MakhloufGharbi: That makes no sense. See my comments on the question.

Comment: @Lightness - perhaps he thinks you can remove the leading zeros from each character and get the same result.

Comment: @owacoder: Well, he's wrong!

Comment: I agree. The protocol seems a little unusual and confusing, so I would give him the benefit of the doubt. After all, we were a little confused at first too!

Comment: this solution doest fuly work but gave me a good vision, my working solution is inversing the index (indian issue perhaps) and converting from ascii to decimal `result = (buffer[3] - '0') << 12;
 result |= buffer[2] - '0' << 8;
 result |= buffer[1] - '0' << 4;
 result |= buffer[0] - '0'; ` thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Um a [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) is 4 bits.  4 bytes is typically a [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) in 32 bit systems

Comment: @owacoder `four byte nibble.` is incorrect.  a nibble is 4 **bits**.  a char typically only occupies 1 **byte**

Comment: Ahh. Sorry. :( I'll fix the typo.